# What Would Be a Good Measure of Feature Importance in Regression?

Tags: regression, feature-engineering, categorical-data, supervised-learning, feature-importances

Doing simple supervised regression where the label is a floating point number (guaranteed positive) and the features are a mix of continuous floating point values and some categorical features.

What would be a good metric of global bivariate dependence that would assign a value to each feature, based on the training dataset. By that I am trying to say

- The importance will be calculated for each feature, not each feature and each sample
- Best if all of them are positive and add up to one, which can be easily achieved by doing a SoftMax as the final step after getting the values otherwise.
- The importance should not be dictated by any specific model, such as CatBoost or XGBoost etc. Just a measure based on the data alone.

If all the features were continuous floats, I would just take the Pearson correlation, but some are categorical as I pointed out. Even for categorical, likely measures like mutual information or entropy can help, but then it is difficult to compare the numbers among features.

Comment: I think you may get better answers if you ask for suitable measures of *bivariate dependence*, rather than feature importances. "Feature importance" is usually associated with a particular model, so the request for model-independent feature importance seems contradictory and might not yield the best answers. There's a list of measure that might be of interest here: https://1library.net/article/measures-of-dependence-bivariate-statistical-dependence.zk6l9rpy

Comment: @KishKash thanks for the comment, and correcting the terminology. Yes, that is what I want and I edited the questions.